# Empty TableView when embedded as a child view controller into a container view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a TableViewController as a child view controller of a container view. For some reason, the table view controller does not show any of its rows. It shows its background color, but the information is absent.
Is this natural?
Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(topBar)
    topBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    topBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    topBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    topBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    topBar.addSubview(subjects)
    subjects.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    subjects.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true

    topBar.addSubview(backButton)

    backButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    backButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true

    let subjectsView = SubjectsTableViewController().view!

    subjectsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    containerView.addSubview(subjectsView)

    subjectsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    subjectsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    subjectsView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    subjectsView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added `SubjectsTableViewController.view` as a subview. This is not enough. You should also add `SubjectsTableViewController` as a child of you view controller. Otherwise, there is not a pointer pointing to `SubjectsTableViewController` causing it `deinit`.

```
let child = SubjectsTableViewController()
addChildViewController(child)
stackView.addArrangedSubview(child.view)
child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that. But apparently, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply rip a view controller's view away from that view controller and shove it into another view. There is a carefully prescribed dance that you must do to make one view controller the child of another, and you are not doing the dance. Therefore your SubjectsTableViewController comes into existence in one line and goes right back out of existence in the next line, leaving no view controller for the poor old table view to talk to. It no longer has any functionality. It is, as you say, empty.